# Cannot install latest version of Numpy (1.22.3)

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am trying to install the latest version of numpy, the 1.22.3, but it looks like pip is not able to find this last release.

I know I can install it locally from the source code, but I want to understand why I cannot install it using pip.

PS: I have the latest version of pip, the 22.0.4

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.22.3 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4, 1.21.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.22.3
```

Comment: Please never attach screenshots, but rather copy the output.

Comment: Please never post terminal output as an image. Just copy-paste it into your question. Please [edit] accordingly and also add information about your OS and python version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please check your Python version. Support for Python 3.7 is dropped since Numpy 1.22.0 release. [[source]](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.22.0)

Comment: You are right, this is the reason. It looks like I have to upgrade my python version.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
pip install numpy
```

It will install the latest version of numpy compatible with your python version. If this somehow that doesn't work, you can always go to the [pypi webpage](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#history) download the version you want from there and install it using.

```
pip install path_to_your_file
```

If your python version is not compatible (as it seems is not), you can always do a virtual environment with a newer python version using pipenv, conda, etc.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do. I would like to understand why my pip is not able to install the latest version by finding in Pypi repository.

Comment: @GGChe then start giving your python version the command you executed etc, but as Ithc said the most likely think is your version is bellow 3.8.

Comment: It's true, I'm using python 3.7 and as @lthc mentioned above, 3.7 was dropped for 1.22 version of numpy. I am going to edit my question for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing NumPy 1.22.3 using pip 22.0.4 and had no issues at all. Try using a virtual environment.

```
python.exe -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html