# Cannot import Tensorflow - Apple Macbook M1

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1, miniconda

I'm trying to use tensorflow, but I can't import it.
I followed the steps on the Apple website to download and install Tensorflow, and everything appears to be ok, but when I try to import tensorflow, I get some errors. What should I do?

Errors:

```
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    () -> handle
```

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

What I did:

- conda create --name myenv python
- conda activate myenv
- conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
- python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
- python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
- conda list:

```
absl-py                   1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h620ffc9_4  
c-ares                    1.18.1               h1a28f6b_0  
ca-certificates           2022.10.11           hca03da5_0  
cachetools                5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.9.24       py310hca03da5_0  
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               22.10.26                 pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               2.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.42.0          py310h95c9599_0  
h5py                      3.6.0           py310h181c318_0  
hdf5                      1.12.1               h160e8cb_2  
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.2               h3b8d789_0  
libclang                  14.0.6                   pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.85.0               hc6d1d07_0  
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0  
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h1a28f6b_0  
libev                     4.33                 h1a28f6b_1  
libffi                    3.4.2                hc377ac9_4  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hca03da5_28  
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h009349e_28  
libnghttp2                1.46.0               h95c9599_0  
libopenblas               0.3.21               h269037a_0  
libssh2                   1.10.0               hf27765b_0  
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               hc6e5704_0  
markdown                  3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.3                  h1a28f6b_3  
numpy                     1.22.3          py310hdb36b11_0  
numpy-base                1.22.3          py310h5e3e9f0_0  
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1q               h1a28f6b_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.2.2          py310hca03da5_0  
protobuf                  3.19.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.10.6               hbdb9e5c_1  
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
requests                  2.28.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                      pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                65.5.0          py310hca03da5_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
sqlite                    3.39.3               h1058600_0  
tensorboard               2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-estimator      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-macos          2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               hb8d0fd4_0  
typing-extensions         4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tzdata                    2022f                h04d1e81_0  
urllib3                   1.26.12                  pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wrapt                     1.14.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.6                h1a28f6b_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5a0b063_0
```

Thanks, Ed

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you try if [`conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) solves the problem?

Comment: Also, please [update your Python if it's <v3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71691188/7789963).

Answer (score 0):

`python -m pip install tensorflow-macos==2.9.0`

Apple has not updated tensorflow-deps to 2.10 now.